# Dynamic form elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I need a form that allows users to dynamically add new fields. In my case, one line contains a label and a textarea, and clicking on the plus sign would add a new line with label and textarea.

I found the plugin http://plugins.jquery.com/project/dynamicField, which does exactly what I want, except for one thing: for each added line, I need the label to contain the number of the line.

Any hints on how this could be done?

Best would probably be to add an event in the plugin like 'AfterAdd' that I can subscribe to and set the label or something?

EDIT: does anyone know a plugin that does this kind of 'dynamic form' thing, where you can add, insert and delete rows?

Thanks,
L

Comment: maybe the question should be: do you know any existing plugins that do that?

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you'd use a plugin for this. It's only a couple of lines of code. Something like:

```
$('#add').click(function() {
    var $container =  $('#container');
    var html ='<label>' 
                + ($container.find('textarea').length + 1) 
                + '</label><textarea></textarea><br />';
    $container.append(html);
});
```

[example here](http://jsfiddle.net/XNCkX/)

Comment: well because my first thought is looking if it has been done before by someone else, to avoid reinventing the wheel. But indeed, seems simple enough. Thank you.

Comment: and i also need a delete link on each row, which makes it more complex of course

Comment: and now i think of it, inserting new rows in between existing rows should also be possible. So it's not that simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [jquery templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/) for that purpose. Something quite clean and great for dynamic DOM generation/insertion.

Comment: Note: The jQuery team has decided not to take this plugin past beta. It is no longer being actively developed or maintained. The docs remain here for the time being (for reference) until a suitable replacement template plugin is ready.